# Fishpig Magento layout issues

Tags: wordpress, magento, magento-1.9, fishpig

Running Magento 1.9.3

I have installed the Fishpig Multisite extension and it is working fine, all talking to each other, but the layout is terrible.

I have followed the customisation instructions on the fishpig website, but no changes I make in the styles.css alter the layout.

Any ideas?

Here's a screenshot to show the bad layout: [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happen if you haven't closed all elements insight your editor. So you should check that first.

If that is not the problem then look if the container is set to `display: block;`. You can find the element name with the Developer-Tools in your Browser.

Comment: I haven't made any alterations to the code, it's straight off the shelf.
It looks like the containers for each blog post are List Items (li) not blocks. 
Any ideas. The link is https://www.babyrice.co.uk/blog/

Comment: Stony is correct. You must be missing a closing </div> tag somewhere. This could be in the WordPress editor or in a custom template. This issue is not present on a clean installation of Magento and the module.